# Put mothers wrong place of birth on online British passport application, how can I correct it?

Tags: uk, passports, uk-citizens

I put my mothers place/town of birth as Br****** instead of De****** I’ve contacted them but yet to get a response, will my application be rejected or could this be corrected with a letter or a meeting?

Comment: Is this online or via the post office. Renewal where youve mailed the old passport back or for a new one?

Comment: did you get the town wrong, or the country?

Comment: It’s a first passport application, I put town wrong, country is correct, I called them and they said an officer would contact me but haven’t heard anything yet.